# Common mistakes with pointers in Go

Tags: pointers, go

I haven't used pointers in a long time, and when I did it was only in an academic setting and I am a bit rusty now thanks to C#/Java/scala.

What are some common mistakes people make with pointers in Golang?

Are there ways of testing if you have used them correctly?  I guess it is always hard to detect a memory leak until things go wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Given that Go is garbage collected and doesn't allow pointer arithmetics there is not much that you can do wrong. You can use `unsafe` package for that but it's name speaks for itself - it's unsafe.

`nil` pointers are still there. Dereferencing them will cause a panic which is somewhat like exceptions in C#/Java - you get a clear error description and a stack trace where it happend.

Memory leaks - GC will do almost everything for you just like in C#/Java. But there is a special case that I know of - slices. Removing an element is usually done by creating another slice like this:

```
a = append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...)
```

this code might leak the element you removed. That's because internally slice is a struct that contains an array (just a pointer), length and capacity. When you remove an element new slice might contain the same array and it will still reference the element you removed. GC will not free it. To solve that you need to nil the element before removing it.

And there is also pointer vs value method receivers confusion. It's not a mistake, more like a design decision you have to make and understand. Method with value receiver will get a copy of the receiver, it can't modify the state. So if you want to modify the state then you need pointer receiver. Also if your structs are big and you don't want them to be copied every time you call a methid you also might want to use pointer receivers.

Answer (score 0):

The common mistake I found is that people forget about pointers inside their complicated structs.

Each slice, map, interface is a pointer. When you have a struct containing another struct containing a pointer, you might just see `S1{s2: S2}`, and you think it's fine to have a struct copied like this: `a=b`, when actually it's not fine, as inside s2, a poiner vatriable, let's say `p`, will have their address copied, and not the value to which it points. When yoy modify the value found at *a.s2.p, the *b.s2.p will return the same value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type S1 struct {
    v int
    s2 S2
}

type S2 struct {
    p *int
}

func main() {
    x := 1
    b := S1{v: 10, s2: S2{p: &x}}
    a := b
    fmt.Printf("a = %+v\nb = %+v\n*a.s2.p = %d\n*b.s2.p = %d\na.s2.p = %p\nb.s2.p = %p\n", a, b, *a.s2.p, *b.s2.p, a.s2.p, b.s2.p)
    *a.s2.p = 5
    fmt.Printf("*a.s2.p = %d\n*b.s2.p = %d\na.s2.p = %p\nb.s2.p = %p\n", *a.s2.p, *b.s2.p, a.s2.p, b.s2.p)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/KQ99KICgbu

This it's a very simple example, and it looks obvious there is an issue, but on bigger applications this might not be that obvious.

This issue appears with channels as well. If you send a pointer, you will get on the other end the same pointer (a copy of your pointer's value, which is an address). In this case, as with the first case, a safe solution is to use a Clone function, to create a cloned object. You send the clone through your channel and don't use it anymore on the sender side.